# Como implementar o Padrão Repository no C# com EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, herança

Quero fazer uma implementação do padrão ***Repository*** onde estarei utilizando o ***EntityFramework*** e tenha o seguinte:

**Interface `IRepository`:**

```cs
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    bool Save(T entity);
    bool Delete(int id);
    bool Delete(T entity);
}
```

**Classe padrão já possuindo algumas implementações para não precisar ser replicado em todas as outras classes *Repository***. Implementação de `IDisposable`:

```cs
public abstract class CustomRepository<T> where T : class, IRepository<T> , IDisposable
{
    protected readonly DataContext context;

    public CustomRepository(DataContext dataContext) {
        this.context = dataContext;
    }

    // Implements of IRepository<T>
    public abstract T GetById(int id);
    public abstract IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    public abstract bool Save(T entity);
    public abstract bool Delete(int id);
    public abstract bool Delete(T entity);

    // implements of IDisposable
    public void Dispose() {
        if (context != null)
            context.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**E então poder implementar minhas classes do padrão *Repository***:

```cs
public class RepresentanteRepository : CustomRepository<Domain.Representante>
{
    public override Domain.Representante GetById(int id) { ... }

    public override IQueryable<Domain.Representante> 
        GetAll(Expression<Func<Domain.Representante, bool>> filter) { ... }

    public override bool Save(Domain.Representante entity) { ... }
    public override bool Delete(int id) { ... }
    public override bool Delete(Domain.Representante entity) { ... }
}
```

Mas não está sendo permitido fazer dessa forma.
Segue mensagem de erro:

> The type 'CS.Domain.Representante' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type 
>   or method 'CS.Repository.CustomRepository'. There is no implicit reference conversion 
>   from 'CS.Domain.Representante' to 'System.IDisposable'.

Então adicionei a herança de `IDisposable` em minha classe `Domain.Representante`.

No entanto ainda sou impedido. Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> The type 'CS.Domain.Representante' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'CS.Repository.CustomRepository'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'CS.Domain.Representante' to
>   'CS.Repository.IRepository'.

## Peruntas:

1. Estou modelando o padrão de forma errada?
2. Tem como resolver o primeiro erro sem precisar de gambiarra e sem precisar fazer com que minhas classes de domínio herdem de `IDisposable`?
3. Como resolver o segundo erro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Usar repositório em cima de Entity Framework é sempre uma má prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696). Nesta resposta, apenas resolvo o problema de código genérico que o autor da pergunta está tendo, mas isso não valida o uso da prática em qualquer aplicação que seja.

---

> Estou modelando o padrão de forma errada?

Não, está correto. Falta só alguns ajustes.

> Tem como resolver o primeiro erro sem precisar de gambiarra e sem precisar fazer com que minhas classes de domínio herdem de IDisposable?

Sim, veja abaixo.

> Como resolver o segundo erro?

Troque:

```
public abstract class CustomRepository<T> where T : class, IRepository<T> , IDisposable
{ ... }
```

Para:

```
public abstract class CustomRepository<T>: IRepository<T>, IDisposable
    where T : class
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 11):

**Camada de Repository**

*A classe `Abstract Respository` é o local aonde é feita a codificação padrão, tendo implementando a Interface IRepository.*

***Interface***

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class, new()
{
    T Create();
    DbSet<E> Create<E>() where E : class, new();        
    T Insert(T model);
    bool Edit(T model);
    bool Delete(T model);
    bool Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    bool Delete(params object[] Keys);
    T Find(params object[] Keys);
    T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IQueryable<T> Query();
    IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
    IQueryable<T> QueryFast();
    IQueryable<T> QueryFast(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
    DbContext Context { get; }
    DbSet<T> Model { get; }
    Int32 Save();
    Task<Int32> SaveAsync();
}
```

---

***Abstract***

*`DbEntities` seria o seu contexto principal*

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{   
    public Repository()
    {
        this.Context = Activator.CreateInstance<DbEntities>();
        this.Model = this.Context.Set<T>();
    }
    public Repository(DbContext Context)
    {
        this.Context = Context;
        this.Model = this.Context.Set<T>();
    }
    public T Insert(T model)
    {
        this.Model.Add(model);
        this.Save();
        return model;
    }
    public bool Edit(T model)
    {
        bool status = false;
        this.Context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        if (this.Save() > 0)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    public bool Delete(T model)
    {
        bool status = false;
        this.Context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        if (this.Save() > 0)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    public bool Delete(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        bool status = false;
        T model = this.Model.Where<T>(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        if (model != null)
        {
            status = Delete(model);
        }
        return status;
    }
    public bool Delete(params object[] Keys)
    {
        bool status = false;
        T model = this.Model.Find(Keys);
        if (model != null)
        {
            status = Delete(model);
        }
        return status;
    }
    public T Find(params object[] Keys)
    {
        return this.Model.Find(Keys);
    }
    public T Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return this.Model.Where<T>(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        return this.Model;
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> Set = this.Query();
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            Set = Set.Include(include);
        }
        return Set;
    }
    public IQueryable<T> QueryFast()
    {
        return this.Model.AsNoTracking<T>();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> QueryFast(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {       
        IQueryable<T> Set = this.QueryFast();
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            Set = Set.Include(include);
        }
        return Set.AsNoTracking();

    }
    public T Create()
    {
        return this.Model.Create();
    }
    public DbSet<E> Create<E>()
        where E: class, new()
    {            
        return this.Context.Set<E>();
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbContext Context
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> Model
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.Context != null)
        {
            this.Context.Dispose();
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return this.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

---

***Respository Album***

Perceba que esse é um dos `Repository`, ou seja, se você tiver mais precisa criar classes dessa maneira herdando da `Class Abstract Respository`. Exemplo `RepositoryNoticia`, `RepositoryCliente`, etc

```
public class RepositoryAlbum : Repository<Album>
{
    public RepositoryAlbum() { }
    public RepositoryAlbum(DbContext Context) : base(Context) { }   
}
```

---

***Instânciando camada***

```
Repository<Album> RepAlbum = new RepositoryAlbum();
```

Comment: Vlw @Crood, é um das camadas que utilizo em meus sistemas, tem várias mas, essa é bem prática.

Comment: +1. Gostei do esquema de ter `Expressions` nos métodos de seleção. Vou incorporar esses protótipos no meu código, inclusive.

Comment: Nesse caso o New() é restrição aonde ele exige construtor sem paramentro. Explicação Site Microsoft: O argumento Tipo deve ter um construtor sem-parâmetros público. Quando usado em conjunto com outras restrições, o new() restrição deve ser especificada pela última vez. @Crood

Comment: OK, @CiganoMorrisonMendez fique a vontade!

Comment: Parabéns @HarryPotter, muito interessante!

Comment: Por nada @TiagoPSilva...