# Padrão de Projeto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Bom utilizo o seguinte padrão de projeto:

[image: Projeto]

Onde a Interface irá se comunicar apenas com a aplicação e essa irá se comunicar com o Repositório. Assim a interface não terá restrições e nem conhecimento de como ocorre a comunicação com a base de dados. No meu caso utilizo o Entity Framework, porém neste esquema posso facilmente estar utilizando outros métodos de comunicação.

A Aplicação conta com duas classes para cada classe do Domínio:

```
public class CartasAplicacao
{
    private readonly IRepositorio<Cartas> repositorio;

    public CartasAplicacao(IRepositorio<Cartas> repo)
    {
        repositorio = repo;
    }

    public void Salvar(Cartas carta)
    {
        repositorio.Salvar(carta);
    }

    public void Excluir(Cartas carta)
    {
        repositorio.Excluir(carta);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Cartas> ListarTodos()
    {
        return repositorio.ListarTodos();
    }

    public Cartas ListarPorId(string id)
    {
        return repositorio.ListarPorId(id);
    }
}
```

E:

```
public class CartasAplicacaoConstrutor
{
    public static CartasAplicacao CartasAplicacaoEF()
    {
        return new CartasAplicacao(new CartasRepositorioEF());
    }
}
```

No RepositorioEF faço o seguinte:

```
 public DbSet<SBE_ST_BannerRotativo> BannerRotativo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cartas> Cartas{ get; set; }

        public Contexto()
            : base("BancoDados")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Contexto>(null);
        }
```

E:

```
 public class CartasRepositorioEF: IRepositorio<Cartas>
    {
        private readonly Contexto contexto;

        public CorpoDocenteRepositorioEF()
        {
            contexto = new Contexto();
        }
        public void Salvar(Cartas entidade)
        {
            if (entidade.Id > 0)
            {
                var cartaAlterar = contexto.Cartas.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
                cartaAlterar.Descricao = entidade.Descricao;
                cartaAlterar.Imagem = entidade.Imagem;
                cartaAlterar.Nome = entidade.Nome;
            }
            else
            {
                contexto.CorpoDocente.Add(entidade);
            }
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Excluir(Cartas entidade)
        {
            var cartaAlterar = contexto.Cartas.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
            contexto.Set<Cartas>().Remove(cartaAlterar );
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IQueryable<Cartas> ListarTodos()
        {
            return contexto.Cartas;
        }

        public Cartas ListarPorId(int id)
        {
            return contexto.Cartas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

Então para utilizar na Interface:

```
var bdcarta = CartasAplicacaoConstrutor.CartasAplicacaoEF();
bdcarta.Salvar(carta);
```

Minhas dúvidas são sobre quais os prós e os contras sobre este modelo de projeto. Se existem outros padrões que são "melhores" que este.

Comment: Acredito que as tags [engenharia-de-software] ou [arquitetura-de-software] são mais adequadas que [design-pattern]

Comment: @gmsantos, editei, obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acho desnecessária a separação para o seu caso em alguns pontos.

A separação em DLLs entre Domínio, Repositório e Aplicação é desnecessária porque você mesmo disse que a Interface irá se comunicar com a aplicação, e a aplicação irá se comunicar com o Repositório. Da forma com que é feito, praticamente todas as classes de todas as DLLs utilizadas para comunicação entre camadas precisam ser públicas, o que só deixa o projeto mais complexo e desnecessariamente exposto (alto acoplamento, baixa coesão).

Neste caso, as três camadas podem perfeitamente estar na mesma DLL, separadas apenas por `namespace`:

- Aplicacao.Core

  - Aplicacao
  - Dominio
  - RepositorioEF

Isto garante que apenas `Dominio` e `Aplicacao` serão expostos para suas interfaces, garantindo baixo acoplamento e alta coesão, como se recomenda em Engenharia de Software.

A existência de um repositório garante que a aplicação estará devidamente isolada do banco, possibilitando a você, inclusive, a retirar o Entity Framework e utilizar outra tecnogia de acesso e persistência em bancos de dados. Melhor ainda que cada repositório implementa a interface `IRepositorio`, garantindo ortogonalidade nas implementações. Seria ainda interessante você usar um padrão genérico de repositório, evitando ter que implementar repositório a repositório (o que não é necessário e vai contra a boa prática de *Don't Repeat Yourself*). [Aqui tem bons exemplos de como fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16122/como-implementar-o-padr%C3%A3o-repository-no-c-com-ef).

---

**EDIT**

A pedidos por comentário, estou colocando a implementação de um repositório genérico:

```
public class AplicacaoGenerica<T>
    where T: class
{
    private readonly IRepositorio<T> repositorio;

    public AplicacaoGenerica(IRepositorio<T> repo)
    {
        repositorio = repo;
    }

    public void Salvar(T entidade)
    {
        repositorio.Salvar(T);
    }

    public void Excluir(T entidade)
    {
        repositorio.Excluir(T);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ListarTodos()
    {
        return repositorio.ListarTodos();
    }

    public T ListarPorId(string id)
    {
        return repositorio.ListarPorId(id);
    }
}

public class RepositorioGenericoEF<T>: IRepositorio<T>
    where TEntity: class
{
    private readonly Contexto contexto;

    public RepositorioGenericoEF()
    {
        contexto = new Contexto();
    }
    public void Salvar(T entidade)
    {
        if (entidade.Id > 0)
        {
            contexto.Entry(entidade).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            contexto.Set<T>.Add(entidade);
        }

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Excluir(T entidade)
    {
        contexto.Set<T>().Remove(entidade);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ListarTodos()
    {
        return contexto.Set<T>.ToList();
    }

    public T ListarPorId(int id)
    {
        return contexto.Set<T>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Portanto:

```
public class CartasAplicacao: AplicacaoGenerica<Cartas>
{

}

public class CartasRepositorioEF: RepositorioGenericoEF<Cartas>
{

}
```

Peguei este exemplo como inspiração: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: Cigano, não entendi a parte final, de implementar repositório a repositório. Coloquei na pergunta como faço atualmente.

Comment: Você implementou a lógica específica para a entidade `Carta`. Um sistema genérico não pediria uma implementação específica. Seria necessário reimplementar apenas casos que são a exceção. Se você tem 20 entidades, terá que escrever 20 repositórios. A idéia é ter que escrever apenas um repositório para as 20 entidades.

Comment: Ainda não está muito claro pra mim. Teria como dar um exemplo?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Coloquei um exemplo pra você.

Comment: Cigano, não estou conseguindo fazer CartasAplicacaoConstrutor...

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Abra outra pergunta, por favor, com o código que está dando problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Se você está separando por namespace apenas, como garante que o projeto 'Ui.Web' não terá acesso direto ao repositório?

Comment: @BrenoSarkis Não referenciando ele diretamente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Mas se ele está na mesma DLL do "domain" por exemplo, não tem como eu garantir isso. Concorda? (não querendo envolver a discussão sobre o seu time entender e saber as limitações de cada camada e 'usá-las para o bem')

Comment: Mas, sinceramente, precisa todo esse cuidado pra um projeto pequeno?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Essa é uma pergunta bem difícil... Eu só queria entender melhor mesmo, obrigado!