# Camada de Aplicação

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, entity-framework-6, engenharia-de-software

Tendo base [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30174/padr%C3%A3o-de-projeto) e [essa outro pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16122/como-implementar-o-padr%C3%A3o-repository-no-c-com-ef), em um ambiente que utiliza o `Entity Framework` e `Asp.net MVC`.

Vejo em muitos exemplos a não utilização da camada de aplicação, uma utilização da camada de dados (`Entity Framework`)  no `Controller`. Então vêm minha primeira dúvida:

**É realmente necessário a utilização dessa camada? E quais as vantagens de sua utilização?**

Seguindo o raciocínio, em um ambiente onde não existem exclusões de dados e sim um campo ativo.

Em relação a listar os dados e exclui-los (alterar o valor do campo ativo):

**Qual camada é responsável por isso? A camada de acesso aos dados, a camada de aplicação, ou então o `Controller`?**

A última dúvida é em relação aos includes.

Implementando este método na camada de dados (`Entity Framework`):

```
 public IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> Set = this.Query();
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            Set = Set.Include(include);
        }
        return Set;
    }
```

**Seria dever da camada de aplicação falar quais includes ele irá utilizar ou então o `Controller`?**

No fundo, não está muito claro para mim, qual a real responsabilidade da camada de aplicação.

Até então para mim a sua única responsabilidade era fazer com que a camada de interação com o usuário (`Controller`) não precisasse ter relação com a camada de dados.

Comment: Vinculada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## É realmente necessário a utilização dessa camada (repositório)? E quais as vantagens de sua utilização?

Não é necessária.

A vantagem da camada é poder escrever mais facilmente testes unitários, porque ao invés de injetar nos repositórios classes que efetivamente acessam dados, você pode injetar outras coisas, como por exemplo, outras classes que trabalhem com dados fictícios e controlados.

## Qual camada é responsável por isso (persistência de dados)? A camada de acesso aos dados, a camada de aplicação, ou então o Controller?

A camada de acesso a dados apenas abstrai as operações de banco conforme você inclui, altera, apaga ou seleciona objetos. É ela que transforma um objeto em um elemento de dados que seu banco de dados entenda.

A camada de aplicação, num contexto MVC, é quase supérflua, porque a interação de dados de diferentes modelos já é feita pelo *Controller*.

Portanto, a responsabilidade de alteração dos **objetos** é do *Controller* e das regras dos *Models*, e de **efetivamente realizar a operação em banco** é de responsabilidade da camada de dados.

## Seria dever da camada de aplicação falar quais includes ele irá utilizar ou então o Controller?

Não. Em teoria a camada de aplicação organiza e valida dados vindos da apresentação. O `Include` faz com que, na seleção, você force o Entity Framework a carregar antecipadamente um determinado dado (aproveitando o recurso de join de um banco relacional, por exemplo, e melhorando o desempenho).

Da forma com que está sendo desenvolvida sua aplicação, o *Controller* está se tornando uma camada oca, sem função. O correto seria deixar de lado o conceito de camada de aplicação e usar apenas o *Controller*.