# Repositório genérico com SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Vendo essa pergunta: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30174/padr%C3%A3o-de-projeto)

Fiquei imaginando se é possível/certo usar um esquema igual esse em um projeto no qual não utilizo algum framework para conexão com banco.

Gostaria de um exemplo de qual a forma correta de ter uma camada DAL, no qual se comunique com SQL SERVER.

Preciso realmente ter um método para todas minhas interações com o banco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

[Dei um exemplo de DAL genérica aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/qual-seria-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-fazer-um-crud-para-um-framework-da-maneira-mai/5658#5658). Na verdade a ideia é uma DAL que se parece muito com um repositório, visto que as operações básicas são geradas a partir da classe passada para a classe comum. Outras operações podem ser escritas em classes derivadas de `Comum`.

Entretanto, é importante dizer que este método é um tanto prolixo e te tomará algum tempo para escrever as operações que não são triviais (por exemplo, um `select` com `join`, e a montagem dos objetos para a camada que solicitou os dados). Ou ainda, no pior dos mundos, você pode trabalhar com o `DataTable` direto, o que é a pior abordagem possível.

Comment: Para um projeto curto, o melhor é eu criar um método para cada operação, para cada table?

Comment: @Felipe O exemplo que coloquei já define pra você 4 métodos por entidade, economizando você de ter que implementar seleção, inclusão, atualização e exclusão para cada entidade do seu projeto.

Answer (score 3):

Não é obrigatório utilizar uma camada somente para a interação com o banco de dados. Vai muito do projeto que você está desenvolvendo.

Por exemplo, se você está construindo uma aplicação simples, um To-Do List ou um projeto com pouquíssimas tabelas ou entidades, e você ou alguém **com certeza** não vá precisar incluir novas funcionalidades no futuro, não vejo que é necessário perder tempo com a camada de dados.

Por outro lado, se seu projeto tem potencial para crescer (incluir novas funcionalidades, alterações frequentes, entre outros) recomendo olhar com carinho, logo de início do projeto, em uma camada de repositórios para sua aplicação, justamente para isolar a lógica do negócio a implementação do banco. Isso trará muito mais facilidades para evoluir sua aplicação.